# There is a form with three empty fields. How can I make a second field with drop-down list depended on items from the first list?

Tags: python, django

There is a form with three fields. Let's call them service, action and input.

```
class InputsExtendedForm(forms.Form):
    #action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    service = forms.CharField(max_length=15, 
        widget=forms.Select(choices=SERVICE_CHOICES))
    action_form = forms.CharField(label='Action', max_length=15)
    input_form = forms.CharField(label='Input', max_length=1000)
```

Lines for service and action are specified in documentation. I created a tuple for service drop-down list.

```
SERVICE_CHOICES = (
    ('Apps', 'Apps'),
    ('Auth', 'Auth'),
    ('Book', 'Book'),
)
```

But for every item in service there are several lines in the action. Is it possible to create a drop-down list action_form, which will display the line depending on the service value? For example a: 1, 2, 4; b: 5, 6, 7

Comment: You'll have to do this with JavaScript, since this is happening on the client side. I would give you more info, but I don't really understand the end result you're looking for.

Comment: I'm creating a simple frontpage for taking info from user. Two first fields can be chosed from suggested variants and the third one is simple text input.